# Rmarkdown .yml navbar menu shows 4th tab weird when knitted to html. Any thoughts?

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown, rstudio, navbar

I'm creating a website from Rmarkdowns with several drop down tabs. The first 3 dropdowns look great but the fourth tab ("Exercises") is much smaller and offset. From looking at the .yml, it doesnt seem to be any different than the previous 3. Can a .yml only house 3 dropdowns? The menu when publishing the index is attached

[image: weird 4th dropdown].

Here's the structure of my .yml:

[image]

I can't seem to find anything on this. I'd like for the 4th tab to look like the previous 3.

Comment: One small difference: You added a hyphen `-` before `menu` in the `Exercises` tab.

Comment: I knew it was going to be something like this. Thank you!